# Is it possible to connect a Netgear EVA8000 to a VGA monitor?

Tags: hdmi, vga, s-video

I have this Netgear EVA8000 http://kbserver.netgear.com/datasheets/enus_ds_eva8000_20070130.pdf

It has a few video outputs:

- HDMI
- RCA component video output
- S-Video port
- SCART connector

Is it possible to convert any of these to VGA to connect a VGA monitor to the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these outputs can be converted to VGA, but HDMI can be converted to DVI.